# Property initial value doesn't change

Tags: ios, properties, swift, boolean, ios8

I have a `BaseViewController` with a boolean property called `hideStatusBar` initialized to `false`.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var hideStatusBar: Bool = false

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return hideStatusBar
    }

}
```

In a subclass derived from this base class, I set `hideStatusBar`'s value to `true`. But it doesn't seem to change the value. I still get false in the `prefersStatusBarHidden` method.

The method certainly works. I changed the property's value and both true and false and tested.

How can you get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work for your BaseViewController subclass:

```
import UIKit

class SubViewController: ViewController {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        hideStatusBar = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    /*
    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return hideStatusBar
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Hello POB. That works! Thank you. Can you please explain why defining it inside the `awakeFromNib` works but not in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: When you push a new UIViewController, `awakeFromNib:` is called before `viewDidLoad:`. In fact, `awakeFromNib:` is called when the controller itself is unarchived from a nib. `viewDidLoad:` is called when the view is created.